# Why does CubeRoot and power of 1/3 give different answers in Mathematica?

Tags: roots, mathematica

I have these 2 functions, which should give identical answers:

```
GPrime[x_] := (1/CubeRoot[x]) + 1

GPrime2[x_] := (1/(x^(1/3))) + 1
```

However, given this:

```
{GPrime[-8],GPrime2[-8]}
```

i get 2 different answers:

$$\frac{1}{2} ,  1 - \frac{1}{2}(-1)^{2/3}$$

why is the answer not $\frac{1}{2}$ for both functions?

Comment: Why would you introduce the extra notation instead of asking "Why `CubeRoot[-8]` and `(-8)^(1/3)` give different answers?"  ?

Comment: Ultimately, it's likely because Mathematica is trying to avoid giving you any one particular root of $-1$ when performing the exponentiation. (There are three complex numbers which cube to give you $-1$.) Mathematica may be assuming the principal root, i.e. $\sqrt[3]{-1} = -1$ in one case; note that if we assume that $(-1)^{2/3} = ((-1)^{1/3})^2 = (-1)^2 = 1$, then the answers agree.

Comment: @FShrike There is no ambiguity . $\sqrt [3]{a^3}=a$ holds $\forall a\in\mathbb R$ . But when $a<0$, the notation $\left (a^3\right)^{\frac 13}≠\sqrt [3]{a^3}$ .

Comment: @lonestudent Technically, cube root is always ambiguous in the complex setting. You say, "the notation [...]" but the notation is used differently in different contexts

Answer (score 4):

For complex numbers $z^w$ is multivaluated. The principal value of $z^w$ is given by $e^{w \log(z)}$ where the principal branch of $\log$ is taken.

Since Mathematica works with complex numbers by default, then $(-2)^{1/3} = e^{\tfrac{1}{3}\log(-2)} = e^{\tfrac{1}{3}(\log(2) + \pi i)}=2^{1/3}(\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2})$.

But when the base $z$ is negative and the exponent is of the form $w=\frac{1}{2n+1}$ one could prefer to use the real $(2n+1)$-th root of $z$. Mathematica have the convenient function `CubeRoot` for the case of cube root and `Surd` for a more general case.

Mathematica's choice could look weird, but that choice allows the function $z^w$ be treated in a general nice way. For example, for fixed $z$ is a continuous function of $w$, while taking the real roots won't even make sense for most exponents.